# How would I set permissions when column = *?

Tags: 2007, permissions, column

I need to set permissions where only certain users have access to view an item when the column equals a certain value.

For example:

User1 can't see item TV when Vendor = "Walmart". 

User2 is able to see item TV.

They can both see all other items, unless Vendor = "Walmart" like above.

Is SharePoint 2007 capable of this OOTB? If not, how would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I handle scenarios like this with on creation workflows using Nintex to set item level permissions.  This can cause some performance issues if the list gets huge.  2007 can't do it out of the box, but with the [SPDActivities](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/) from codeplex, you can.

An alternative would be to limit access to the list, and use some web part pages with filtered views, audience targetting, and library permissions to handle displaying the data in a more secure fashion if we're talikng thousands of items.

Bamboo has a product for 2007 called List Item Security that allows you to create secure columns that only a select group of people can view.  If the user isn't part of the group, it abstracts the data.